# sax parser is skips charcters after printable ascii characters using java program

Tags: java

I have response xml in string format. I have a xmlstring like this Eg : L’équipe dirigeante accueille Dieter Zetsche à l’usine de Maubeuge. after parsing using sax parser I have only l . The parser is skips all the characters after ’ this charcters. Can any one help how to retrieve entire text after parsing

Comment: Do you have specific encoding declared in the xml document?

Comment: no I don't have encode type

Comment: Actually the characters is apostrophe. while display in browser it is fine when getting as a string format in java it displays &#8675; like after this amberson symbol sax parser is skips the remaining letter.

Comment: @Ravi: Nope. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Accented characters are not ASCII. They're some other encoding, and they're likely to collide with the UTF8 encoding which XML defaults to. Declare the proper encoding, or express those characters properly in UTF8.

Comment: Actually the characters is apostrophe. while display in browser it is fine when getting as a string format in java it displays &#8675; like after this amberson symbol sax parser is skips the remaining letter.

Comment: That is NOT an ASCII apostrophe. It's some byte value over 127, with the high bit set. In UTF8, that signals the start of a multi-byte character, which is why it absorbs the next byte. Either switch back to ASCII, or declare the proper encoding, or express the characters properly in UTF8.